# If YouTube in Redactor Then Wrap in Div

Tags: redactor, conditional

So I have been using [this](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) CSS Tricks responsive video trick for years. The problem I'm having is that this new Craft site I built imported data over from EE into a single Redactor field.

Is there any way to run s conditional check that `if` there is a YouTube video embedded that would wrap a `div` around said content?

I'm probably asking too much but Craft has been amazing for the past few years I've using it. I fear the only way to do this would be to run an elaborate `MYSQL` commands to wrap that content in a `div` (or use JS to wrap each iframe) but I would love to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Retcon](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) plugin!

> Retcon is a small Craft CMS plugin offering a series of easy-to-use Twig filters for manipulating HTML content.

Specifically, it sounds like you need the [wrap](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Wrap) method:

```
{{ entry.body|retconWrap('iframe', '.videoWrapper') }}
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass multiple classes here? For example '.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-16by9'

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor I'd recommend posting [a new question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). This answer is almost 2 years old. Feel free to link back to this thread for reference.

Comment: I actually found a solution using Retcon. I feel like I should post it in case someone else has the same question.

Comment: Sounds good! Asking & answering your own question is actually encouraged here on SE. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to sound thick here ... should I post it as a comment, put it as a new answer here, or just ask a whole new question then answer it? I think it's the third option?

Comment: Yup, the third option. Post a new question (reference this Q&A if you'd like), then you can immediately post your own answer to it. You can even do both simultaneously, by clicking the "Answer your own question" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

This article describes Twig macro that makes embedded youtube players responsive and lazy-loaded:

[Responsive and lazy-loaded youtube videos with Craft CMS](http://craftsnippets.com/articles/responsive-and-lazy-loaded-youtube-videos-with-craft-cms?s=s)